# What is the present tense verb form of apoptosis?

Tags: cell-biology, apoptosis

For example, if I want to say something along the lines of "this signaling pathway causes a cell to go through the process of apoptosis", but I want to shorten the phrase "go through the process of apoptosis" to one word, what would that word be? I've been saying "apoptose" so far but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: Apoptosise? I think most people would just phrase it as you have.

Comment: Personally, I would say "undergo apoptosis" being both shorter and not risking coining new word forms.

Answer (score 5):

According to Google Scholar, there were [~40000 hits](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=apoptose&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) for "apoptose" and ~[120k hits](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22undergo%20apoptosis%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) for "undergo apoptosis" in published literature, both of which had significant numbers of high-impact articles.

Therefore, it is clear that both expressions are sufficiently used in literature for either to be used.

Personally, I would say "undergo apoptosis" being both shorter than your original phrase and not risking coining new word forms.